# Ruby parse string with regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I parse `[3 Series] 315` to generate 2 substrings: `series = "3 series"` and `model = "315"` using regexp in Ruby? My following code gives syntax error:

```
"[3 Series] 315".split /[|\]\s/
```

series can be a string or just a number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
_, series, model = "[3 Series] 315".scan(/(\d+\s\w+|\d+)/)
```

**OR**

```
_, series, model = "[3 Series] 315".split /\[|\]\s/

series
# => "3 Series"
model
# => "315"
```

Comment: `_, series, model = "[3 Series] 315".scan(/(\d+\s\w+|\d+)/)` is incorrect, scan returns a enumerble, and it won't get each value in each varible. But you could do as [roninblade answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18441277/3866548): `series, model = "[3 Series] 315".scan(/(\d+\s\w+|\d+)/).to_a.flatten`

Answer (score 4):

```
re = '\[(\w \w*)\] (\d*)'
str = "[3 Series] 315"
_, series, model = str.match(re).to_a
=> ["[3 Series] 315", "3 Series", "315"]

series
=> 3 Series

model
=> 315
```

Answer (score 3):

another way to do it

```
> result, series, model = /\[(.+)\] (.+)/.match(str).to_a.flatten

> series
# => "3 series"

> model
# => "315"
```